# 4.2.1 is overriding Base SDK to 4.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I'm getting this message in parenthesis next to the device when installing the app through Xcode. `xxxx's iPhone(4.2.1 is overriding Base SDK to 4.3)`

The deployment target for the app is 4.0. Any ideas why I am getting this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand:

- You're using 4.3 as base SDK specified in target settings
- You have 4.2.1 installed on your device
- You have 4.0 as your deployment target

the "override base SDK to 4.3" is a reminder you're building against 4.3 headers and libraries and not 4.2.1 (because the 4.2.1 indication is referring to the operating system installed into the device, and thus can be misleading). If you have more SDKs installed in your xcode (such as 5.0 beta or older 3.x SDKs) other schema choices should appear.

In my case I have 3.1.2 and 3.1.3 installed and two more entries appears, but both are missing the "overriding base sdk to" indication, so I don't know whether I'm building for 3.1.2 or 3.1.3 unless i check the build logs. I guess this is due to missing support for older <3.2 SDKs in xcode 4.

To know which SDK version and which deployment target are you building you can check the build log: look at any compiler command line for the `-isysroot` option, which specifies the SDK location (aka base SDK), and the `-miphoneos-version-min=x.x.x` which specifies deployment target.